# Problema ao renderizar partials dinamicamente

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="0">
  <% @time_line.each do |time_line| %>
    <%= render partial: partial_name( get_type(time_line) ), locals: { register: time_line } %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**@time_line** é uma variável que concatena registros de vários models. Pra complicar mais, para cada tipo de objeto, eu preciso de uma view diferente (é requisito do projeto, eu não posso mudar). Então, pra deixar mais simples de dar manutenção depois, pensei em fazer desta forma acima. Os códigos dos métodos que eu usei pra tentar chamar as partials dinamicamente:

```
def partial_name(class_name)
  partial_names = {
    "Custa" => 'financial',
    "Andamento" => 'course',
    "Movimentacaoweb" => 'web_movement',
    "Publicacao" => 'publication',
    "Audiencia" => 'hearing',
    "Anotacao" => 'anotation'
  }

  partial_names[class_name.to_s]
end

def get_type(obj)
 obj.class.to_s == 'Mensagem' ? obj.model.to_s : obj.class.to_s
end
```

Por algum motivo, quando eu executo, dá o seguinte erro:

> 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.

Alguém sabe me explicar o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: essa mensagem ocorre na execução do <%= render partial:... ? %>

o def partial_name esta dentro de um helper?

Comment: Sim.... dentro de um helper.

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu posso estar pirando mas tem certeza que @time_line é uma variável de instância?

Se realmente for, ela sempre será `nil` no teu contexto pois você está chamando `time_line` ao invés de  `@time_line`!! Então para resolver o problema apenas troque esta linha:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="0">
  <% @time_line.each do |time_line| %>
    <%= render partial: partial_name( get_type(time_line) ), 
                        locals: { register: time_line } %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

para:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="0">
  <% @time_line.each do |time_line| %>
    <%= render partial: partial_name(get_type(@time_line)), 
                        locals: { register: @time_line } %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

### UPDATE 02

Estive analisando novamente e vi, um possível problema: "a sua declaração do render".
Que tal trocar para:

```
<%= render partial_name(get_type(time_line)), locals: { register: time_line } %>
```

Valeuu!

Comment: @time_line é sim uma variável de instância...
Não tem com eu utilizar da forma como você sugeriu porque ela contém um Array de objetos do ActiveRecord. Por isso que eu usei o 'each'. 'time_line' representa o objeto correspondente a cada iteração.

Comment: Beleza, eu alterei a resposta, pelo que me lembre sempre usei sem o hash com a key: partial! testa do jeito que eu coloquei ali, (estou sem o pc aqui para ver se dá certo! :/ )

Comment: Se essa última resposta não der certo, cola um debug do teu array de objetos aí! :D

Answer (score 0):

O Rails sabe encontrar a partial de um model automaticamente.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

> If you have an instance of a model to render into a partial, you can
>   use a shorthand syntax:
>
> `<%= render @customer %>`
>
> Assuming that the @customer instance variable
>   contains an instance of the Customer model, this will use
>   _customer.html.erb to render it and will pass the local variable customer into the partial which will refer to the @customer instance
>   variable in the parent view.

Então, seu código poderia ser alterado para:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="0">
  <% @time_line.each do |tl| %>
    <%= render tl, locals: { register: tl } %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```